# Using one prop value in another prop in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-table

I have a react table component as below -

```
 <ReactTable
         data={instances.data}
         columns={columns}
         filterable
         pageSize= {this-value-needs-to-come-from-data-prop-above}
     />
```

I want to derive the value of prop `pageSize` - as the length of the data prop. So value of `pageSize` prop of this component to come from another prop value - the value of `data`. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Use the instances.data size?

Comment: @BernhardJosephus The thing is , on applying table filter , `data` prop changes but not the `instance.data`.

Comment: May I know the library you used for the ReactTable component?

Comment: @BernhardJosephus library used is - react-table

Comment: I take a look at the documentation but it seems there is no way to achieve what you need easily. The closest thing that I can suggest is to add `minRows` props and set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is instead of trying to pass pageSize as a prop, you can just pass data as a prop and then from within the ReactTable component, You can calculate pageSize based on the data prop.